# Outlook: search for mails that don't have a particular category

Tags: email, outlook, categories

I categorize my mails with different categories (like: work, important, later).
When I want to search for mails that have the tag important, I type (or select):

```
category:="Important"
```

until here everything is ok :-)

Now I want to search all the mails that don't have the category important.
How do I do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do this by putting a - on the place where the = is.

```
category:-"Important"
```

It's that simple :-)